# Add storage class to S3ContentStore

Tags: spring-content-community-project

We are already using spring content with content stores for JpaContentStore and FileContentStore. Now we are adding support for S3ContentStore but unfortunately we miss one important thing when uploading a file via setContent: **a parameter for the storage class**.

I have reads lots of things but I don't know how do get a solution for it. One of my ideas was to create a new MyS3ContentStore which simply extends S3ContentStore with an new method like

```
@LockParticipant
E setContent(E entity, InputStream content, StorageClass storageClass);
```

I have also created an implementation for that like that

```
@Transactional
public class MyS3ContentStoreImpl<E, CID extends Serializable> extends DefaultS3StoreImpl<E, CID>
        implements MyS3ContentStore<E, CID> {

    public AMyS3ContentStoreImpl(ApplicationContext context, ResourceLoader loader, MappingContext mappingContext, PlacementService placementService, S3Client client, MultiTenantS3ClientProvider provider) {
        super(context, loader, mappingContext, placementService, client, provider);
    }

    @Override
    public E setContent(E entity, InputStream content, StorageClass storageClass) {
        return setContent(entity, content);
    }
}
```

I also read that I must use @EnableS3Stores with defines basePackages telling where to find my classes.

Finally I have create a store for my concrete entity ArchivedFile:

```
@Repository
public interface MyS3Store extends MyS3ContentStore<ArchivedFile, UUID> {}
```

I tried several things but I cant get i working. Depending on what I do my classes are not found or I get an error because more than one bean with name 'myS3Store#StoreFragments' is created. As I did lots of things I can't tell here exactly what caused what.

So my question is:

What is the best way to achieve what I want? Are there some conventions I muss follow? Any other things I could miss? I have checked f.e. the azure example but this is a complete new Store and there are lots of classes in different packages and I´m not sure if I need all that classes and if I have to follow some packaging rules.